# Electron app not working on Windows

Tags: windows, electron, electron-builder

I have an electron app I develop on MacOS and build for Windows. I can properly install the .exe that's generated from electron-builder on to Windows.

When I run the app on Windows, I get a spinning loader for 1-2 sec. and then nothing happens. The app, when running properly, shows an icon in the task bar and opens a browser window for the user to login.

I'm using electron-log, but nothing is printed to the logs. It seems like the app is dying before it can start. I'm looking through Event Viewer and don't see anything obvious. I feel like I'm missing something and don't have a great way to understand what's happening.

Any suggestions on where to look on Windows 10 to understand why an electron app isn't doing anything?

Comment: did you try launching it  with command line ? , may you can see the error there, it has to be crashing on you main, possibly due to a file  'location' problem, but I'm just guessing

Comment: Great point. I tinkered with it locally and it turns out removing the call to "mainWindow.setPosition(x, y, false)" fixes the issue. No to figure out why!